# Correct way to use yarn/npm from node script

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Inside my script I want to use some functionality from `yarn`/`npm`

Like get results of `yarn info packageName`. I could spawn command and get output, but I believe there should be more correct way to do that.

Can't find any documentation about usage of `yarn` as package. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NPM and Yarn were designed as CLI tools. It's possible to load them with `require` but since executable script does a lot of work on options processing, this isn't practical.

The most straightforward and predictable way is to run them with `child_process` `spawn` or `exec`. There are [`npm-programmatic`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-programmatic) and [`yarn-programmatic`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-programmatic) third-party packages that do this internally. Since their APIs don't necessarily cover 100% of CLI functionality, it may still be beneficial to run commands directly.

There are open issues for [NPM](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20876) and [Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4514) regarding programmatic use.